# Checking specific column in data source created of multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

A data source called 'D_UNITED_DATA' is created of multiple tables that are joined together, mostly by inner join.

I need to check how the column called 'Music Order' from table 'Music Records' looks like after being joined and added to that data source.

How to check that specific column?

I tried

```
SELECT 'Music Order'
FROM IRB.D_UNITED_DATA
```

but it just writes out Music Order many times.

I am using Oracle SQL Developer.

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer is a client application used to connect to a database; it is **NOT** a database. Which RDBMS are your connecting to?

Comment: I know it is the application, NOT a database. Just wanted to mention which client app I am using.

Comment: The client is (typically) irrelevant as it is the syntax supported by the database that matters. In Oracle you use `"identifier"`, in SQL Server you use `[identifier]`, etc. so your solution requires us to know which RDBMS and **NOT** which client.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle:

- `'value'` is for string literals.
- `"identifier"` is a (case-sensitive) quoted identifier for a column/table/alias/etc.
- `identifier` is a (non-quoted) identifier (that will be implicitly converted to UPPER-CASE and allow you to effectively use case-insensitive identifiers).

You probably want:

```sql
SELECT Music_Order
FROM IRB.D_UNITED_DATA
```

or, if you really do have a space in the column name:

```sql
SELECT "Music Order"
FROM IRB.D_UNITED_DATA
```

If you need to `JOIN` a `Music Records` table then include that in the query:

```sql
SELECT "Music Order"
FROM   IRB.D_UNITED_DATA d
       INNER JOIN "Music Records" mr
       ON d.something = mr.something
```

*Note: Using quoted identifiers is considered bad practice as you have to use quoted identifiers everywhere the column is referenced and have to exactly match the case used in the table definition; it is considered better practice to use non-quoted identifiers and not include spaces in identifiers.*

Comment: Hmm I did try what you suggested, but I got error: 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier". Maybe column name is not right. It is a column name that I am seeing in Tableau though.  Can you please tell me how to check the column name in Oracle SQL?

Comment: @Ravena `SELECT * FROM your_table_name WHERE ROWNUM = 1` or `DESCRIBE your_table_name` or `SELECT * FROM user_tab_columns WHERE table_name = 'your_table_name'`.